# Win+E vs explorer command - the difference?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer, thumbnails

The background is that I wanted Windows Explorer to remember file / folder icons position in thumbnail view in one specific folder. As I often use Total Commander to browse through the files, I've first defined a hot directory entry that would point to my special folder.

After that I've realized that it would be safer to open the special folder in Windows Explorer instead in Total Commander (so that new files / folders copied to the special folder would not move / change the position of files / folders already present in the folder). So in Total Commander I've defined a hot directory command to be: explorer "path to the special folder".

Now if I press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> and navigate to my special folder, the folder remembers the icon positions (in thumbnail view) - nice. The funny thing though is that if open the same folder through the 'explorer' command from within Total Commander, the folder remembers a second, separate icon 'layout'.

So now I can have two custom icon 'layouts' by accessing the folder either through <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> or through 'explorer' command.

1. Why is that happening?
2. How to access the folder from within Total Commander so the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> icon layout would display in Windows Explorer?

Comment: Which layout you see when you navigate into this folder via My Computer? Do you work under administrator account?

Comment: User account with administrator privileges, there are two separate layouts, one layout is different from another and both layouts are remembered separately.